# HDMI for Jetson Nano contradictions in guides

Tags: pcb, hdmi, jetson

For my drone, I want to develop a custom Jetson carrier board with minimal required interfaces. For quick debugging, I would like to add an HDMI port on the PCB. However, I’m not familiar with HDMI and I found some contradictions between guides.

In most guides, it’s written the impedance of the trace should be 100 Ohm. I found some pretty easy schematics examples
[image]

However, in the Jetson Nano design guide, there are more required elements as these capacitors and Rs resistors, which I do not completely understand the purpose…

Schematic:

[image]

At the end, there is this figure, which tells us to have 500 Ohm impedance traces where all segments should be 100 Ohm :/

Schematic:
[image]

I can blindly reproduce the carrier board but I would like to understand better what I’m going to do.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Where does it say 500 ohm? I only see segments of 100 ohm traces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capacitors are there for signal decoupling and the protection of the Jetson together with the resistors.

For protection, there are many different implementations possible and it may vary. It doesn't mean that one or another is wrong, it's often a question of cost vs effectiveness and may vary on the chip itself, some are designed for having decoupling caps, some are designed for not.

For example, ethernet also has many different implementations, decoupling caps, chokes, no chokes, etc...

If you are developing for the jetson, your best bet is to copy their schematics as it was tested in this configuration.

Comment: Thx, and for the impedance required shall I keep the 500 Ohms as written in the guide? Or reduce it to 100 Ohms

Comment: I would recommend following the guide, but check if they have a reference design and the BOM. 500ohm trace impedance doesn't necessarily mean to put 500ohm resistors. The second schematic says "see note 4", you can check this one.

Comment: Sure it is not the resistor but the trace impedance from the board to the connector as shown in fig 3. Each trace is 100 ohm resulting to 500 ohms

Comment: @Yann The answer is kind of incorrect, I mean sure the components are there to protect the interface from HDMI display blowing it up, but that's because the Jetson interface is not even designed to be directly electrically compatible with HDMI to begin with. And the trace impedance is not 500 ohms at any point in the system, it is always 100 ohms. Traces of 100 ohm impedance don't add up.

Comment: @Yann you can have a look at https://pcbway.medium.com/impedance-matching-in-high-speed-pcb-design-9f070db8b8f4 - Usually, impedance matching is handled by your PCB design software or by the PCB manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in circuitry is because the Jetson cannot be directly connected to a HDMI connector.

The Jetson is actually having a DisplayPort output which requires AC coupling and can thus use lower supply voltages, but at the same time it cannot handle higher DC voltages required by HDMI. The output protocol between DP and HDMI can be selected in software, but it cannot be electrically compatible.

So the components are there to adapt the DisplayPort electrical interface to be compatible with HDMI interface.

Impedance is 100 ohms.

Comment: Would be it easier in this case to simply put a Display Port instead of HDMI?

Comment: That is a whole another question and a matter of opinion what is easier. You seem to have the schematics already so you can judge yourself.